# How to publish angular 2 app with docker nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, angular2-routing, load-balancing

My NGINX config

```
worker_processes      1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include             mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  sendfile on;

  keepalive_timeout   65;

  server {
    listen  80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
  }
}
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.11-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD ./dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

After making this as image and running as direct IP and port number is working fine.

After adding to the load balancer it not working.

My load balancer NGINX

```
upstream ui-service{
    server containerip:80;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxxxxx.com;
    location /group-management-ui/ {
        proxy_pass  http://ui-service;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Problem is to resolve the asserts :

My URL :

https://xxxxxx.com/group-management-ui/

But try to resolve the asserts from the about different folder

https://xxxxxx.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

I try to add the base to match with this

```
<base href="/group-management-ui">
```

But no luck... :(